# Is HTTPS necessary on internal proxies?

Tags: ssl, iis, https, haproxy

I have drawed the following chart to help explain our situation:

[image]

We have an API running on the KESTREL WebServer in the back end. This is running as several instances in docker containers. In front of this, we have a HAProxy Load Balancer which directs the traffic to the Kestrel server with the least connections.

All of this so far is only available internally on our network.

We have one server accessible from the internet, running IIS on port 80 and 443. 
In IIS we have added a SSL Certificate which encrypts the communication between the end user and our first entry point.

Is there any further need to encrypt the communication between IIS which proxies the request to our HAProxy on the internal network, and from there on, necessary to encrypt communication from HAProxy to the backends?

As far as my knowledge goes, the only benefit of this, would be that nobody on the internal network at our office can listen to the connections going between the servers, but please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: You can/might, but it really depends on the performance/security requirements of your web applications. If security is your top priority, more encryption does help. If performance is your desire, then raw HTTP is of course fastest. So I vote to close this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LexLi. However, as of closing the question, I still feel like this is a topic that deserves a good explanation, as job positions these days often requires developers to fill more than just a position as a developer, and go more into hosting as well. I do understand that the coms between the end user and our main endpoint is encrypted, and thus can't be hacked. But I would like to know more about, or just simply confirming / dismissing my theory of the only weakness being someone on "the inside" listening.